# Why does this cross sign stay gray in Safari iOS?

Tags: css, ios, unicode, safari, webkit

I just spent too much time figuring out why my `<button>` doesn't want to display white text color on iOS Safari. It's a button to close modal, defined like this:

```html
<button type="button">✖</button>
```

Here's what I got:

[image: Button with gray cross, yikes!]

I was sure I'm missing something about, as we all know that buttons are not the easiest to style. But after applying `color: #fff;` and `-webkit-appearance: none` I expected it to work. I finally thought of trying other characters and, for my surprise, here's the result:

[image: Button with some wild crosses]

Apparently my CSS was correct, it was the character itself to blame. Now, I'm really curious what happened. At first I thought that maybe that cross of my choice was emoji, but doesn't seem to be. The first one is just a regular capital X (1 byte) and all others are 3 bytes. Emoji are 4 bytes, right?

My question, mostly for my curiosity, is: why does this cross stay gray?

For reference, here's the crosses I tested: `X ✕ ☓ ✖ ✗ ✘`, the fourth one being the one. The font I used is *Tahoma*, but I'm not sure if that matters for Unicode characters after all. The problematic cross sign is called *HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X* (U+2716).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystery solved. This particular cross character has its very close emoji brother. The cross itself is `U+2716`, which is decimal `10006`.

But there's also emoji, which looks almost exactly the same, except being grey (at least in Apple's interpretation) and with mild shadow. This emoji is made of two combined characters:

1. The same `U+2716` cross
2. A character called `VARIATION SELECTOR-16`, being `U+FE0F` or decimal `65039`

It looks like Safari on iOS converts `U+2716` to its emoji counterpart under some circumstances. One of those cases is putting it inside the `<button>`.

Comment: Wow that's incredibly annoying

Comment: @Gavin indeed, however it looks like they fixed it somewhere over time. In macOS Sonoma it displays the cross sign inside button normally, I can change its color :)

Comment: good to hear. I was thinking I was having this issue, but it turned out the client accidentally pasted in the emoji ;)

Comment: is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, emojis do not work the same way. Some of them are textual symbols and some of them are just plain emojis. I do this simple trick and this works most of the time:

```
element {
  color: transparent;  
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 green;
}
```

Comment: This character doesn't seem to be an emoji though.

Comment: It's also worth noting that it does work properly when not in `<button>`. Super weird, maybe just Safari bug?

Comment: It's an emoji and called `Multiplication Symbol` by Apple. Source: `https://emojipedia.org/multiply/`. I don't think it is a bug. Just test it with the trick that I shared. I think it will work

Comment: Good find, although it seems to be another character. I copy-pasted it to MySQL query to check the byte length and it's 6 for that one.

Comment: I am not sure how this works deeply maybe some research can lead to an answer, but I guess Safari or Chrome or any other platform can override the emoji.

Comment: I did some more investigation and I found out what happened! You can take a look at my answer if you're curious like I was :)

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer, since it guided me to investigate emoji.